# How to make non-interactive Grid overlay?

Tags: css, grid, material-ui

I want to have the Grid visible on my site while i'm developing it, a-la Adobe XD style [(link to image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDFSz.png), to better understand how much place elements are taking(or should take).

The code underneath works but I have to manually specify Width of the grid when setting position to 'fixed' or 'absolute'.

There must be a more elegant way to do this.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
const testGridItems = () =>{
  var list = new Array();
  for(let i=0; i<12; i++){
  list.push( 
      <Grid item xs={1}>
        <div  align='center' 
           style={{  
             height: '100vh',
             position:'relative', 
             backgroundColor: '#F6BB42', 
             opacity:0.2}
           }>
             {i+1}
        </div>
      </Grid>
  )
  }

return list;
}


const testGrid = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container
      style={{
       width:1200,
       position:'fixed'
      }} 
      spacing={24} >

      { testGridItems() }
     </Grid>

  )
}
```